Quantum mechanics with a classical Chern-Simons term
In this post, quantum mechanics falls under what is traditionally called "first quantization". This is in contrast to quantum field theory which traditionally falls under "second quantization".
In textbook quantum mechanics, a system $A$ with states $\{S_i\}$ is represented by the subset of unit trace and positive-definite vectors in the Banach algebra of trace-class linear operators over a Hilbert space, denoted $\overline{\mathcal{B}}^+(\mathcal{H}) \subset \mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$. The dynamics of the system are generated by a Hamiltonian $H \in \mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$ via a dynamic relation called the von Neumann equation
\begin{equation}
    \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \rho = -\frac{i}{\hbar}[H, \rho], \quad \rho \in \overline{\mathcal{B}}^+(\mathcal{H}).
\end{equation}
We observe that traditionally the Hamiltonian may include terms we call classical potential terms. A canonical example of a classical field term is the Coulomb interaction term in the basic hydrogen atom Hamiltonian:
\begin{equation}
H_{hyd} := -\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\nabla^2 - \frac{e^2}{4\pi\epsilon_0r}.
\end{equation}
Another example of a classical potential is the Chern-Simons potential defined as follows. Consider a $\mathfrak{g}$-valued connection $1$-form $\omega \in \mathfrak{g} \otimes \Omega^1(P)$ where $P$ is a principal bundle. A Chern-Simons potential $A$ is the pullback of $\omega: P \to \mathfrak{g} \otimes T^*P$ via a global section $\sigma: M \to P$ satisfying the equation of motion obtained via stationizing an action containing at least the following terms
\begin{equation}
    S = \frac{k}{8\pi^2}\int_M \kappa\left( A \stackrel{\wedge}{,} dA + \frac{1}{3} [A \stackrel{\wedge}{,} A] \right), \quad k \in \mathbb{R}\backslash\{0\}
\end{equation}
where $\kappa$ is the Killing form with domain extended from $\mathfrak{g}$ to $\mathfrak{g}$-valued $1$-forms.
I have only ever seen Chern-Simons talked about in the context of (classical or) quantum field theory, not in quantum mechanics. Can one write down a quantum mechanics Hamiltonian that includes a Chern-Simons potential? Can this potential be coupled with particles?

FWIW, in QM one can always include a 1D CS term in the worldline theory: An electric potential term.
